# Unable to build a specific piece of code dynamically

Tags: jquery

I need to build this structure which has been provided to me in css dynamically .

```
<div id="myordersdiv">
    <ul>
        <li class="myorderhead"><h5>My Orders <i>2</i></h5></li>
        <div class="content">
            <div id="ordersdiv" style="display:none"></div>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to build this this way

HTML Section

```
<div id="myordersdiv">
    <ul>
        <li class="myorderhead"><h5>My Orders <i>2</i></h5></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
var dataa = '<div id="ordersdiv" style="display:none"></div>';
$(".myorderhead").prepend(dataa);
$("#myordersdiv").prepend(buildcart);
```

Please let me know where is the mistake i am doing ??

Comment: Your HTML is invalid - you cannot have a `div` as a direct child of a `ul`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
   $("#myordersdiv ul").append(dataa);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this .**[after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)**,

```
$(".myorderhead").after(dataa);
```

Your structure also has `<div class="content">`. So use this,

```
$(".myorderhead").after('<div class="content">'+dataa+'</div>');
```

Note: Try appending all of these in a `<li>` element. You cant have a `<div>` under `<ul>`